# Cannot build package with dot in the name with newer version of Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

since I updated my version of `Rcpp` to `0.12.11` (I tested it works for `0.12.10`) I cannot build my package anymore.
Actually creating a new package called `dot.test` from `RStudio` cannot be built.

```
Updating dot.test documentation
Loading dot.test
Re-compiling dot.test
'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD INSTALL '/pxfs/data/statquant/public/dot.test'  \
  --library='/tmp/RtmpZARXxv/devtools_install_1ef63ab8fde6' --no-R --no-data  \
  --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch  \
  --no-test-load 

* installing *source* package ‘dot.test’ ...
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/lxhome/statquant/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp:20:46: error: ‘dot’ was not declared in this scope
     {"dot.test_rcpp_hello_world", (DL_FUNC) &dot.test_rcpp_hello_world, 0},
                                              ^
```

---

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0
```

---

```
R> system('which g++')
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++
R> system('g++ --version')
g++ (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If that's understandable that `C++` and a package name with `.` might be asking for problems ***it is not explicitly forbidden*** (that I know of). 
There are tons of packages like `data.table` that have a dot in the name

My questions are then:

- Did I miss an explicit rule from R-core ?
- Do a `.` in the name implies I cannot use `Rcpp::compileAttributes` anymore ?
- Is there a quick fix that would enable me to build and still use `Rcpp>0.12.10` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug which Kirill reported to me the other day (in person), by now filed on GitHub ... and which should get fixed "soon".

See https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/721 for more and progress.

The quick fix, for now, is to use a hand-edited `src/init.c` until `compileAttributes()` gets fixed.

Comment: And the fix is in, and has been merged.

Comment: I don't know if it is related to this question but when I create a package called, for example, `a.b` and I use `// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]`. Rcpp creates to headers in inst/include/: `a.b.h` and `a.b_RcppExports.h`, then I get the error `fatal error: a_b_RcppExports.h: No such file or directory`. As the compiler says, the first file points to file `a_b_RcppExports.h`, which has not been created. I'm using  Rcpp_0.12.12.1

Comment: IIRC R would allow a dot in the package name, but Rcpp via Attributes does not for the reason you encountered.  I'd avoid the dot, or else you have to forgo the (rather nice semi-automated) tooling.

Comment: Ok, I'll forget the semi-automatisation tool. Thank you!

Comment: I am saying if you want to create that way (ie using generated  `RcppExport.{cpp,R}`) then you cannot have a dot in the name as we cross over from R requirements to C++ requirements.  If you write all you code by hand and don't use Rcpp Attributes then it can work.